# angularjs variable issue after update

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem after that angularjs update 1.4.4 to 1.5.0

the html code is :

```
<li ng-repeat="menubar in menubars">
<a ng-if="menubar.name != 'test'" href="{{ menubar.url }}" ng-click='trackOutboundLink("Menubar_{{ menubar.name }}", "{{ menubar.url }}");'>{{ menubar.name }}</a>
</li>
```

the controller have this code:

```
$rootScope.trackOutboundLink = function(tag, url) {
    console.log(tag);
    console.log(url);
};
```

before I update the angularjs, the console will output the correct value, but after I update to 1.5.0, the output will become 'Menubar_{{ menubar.name }}' and '{{ menubar.url }}', I don't how to fix this problem,  and angularjs cannot rollback, so is there any method to fix this?

Comment: the browser shows the correct value, and the tag's attribute is correct too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has an error because of the curly braces in ng-click.
The parameters should look like below:

```
<li ng-repeat="menubar in menubars">
  <a ng-if="menubar.name != 'test'" href="{{ menubar.url }}" ng-click=" trackOutboundLink('Menubar_'+ menubar.name, menubar.url);">{{menubar.name }}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect. ng-click expects an angular expression. And angular expressions can't contain double mustaches. It should be

```
ng-click="trackOutboundLink('Menubar_' + menubar.name, menubar.url)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove curly brackets from `ng-click`.

```
ng-click="trackOutboundLink('Menubar_' + menubar.name, menubar.url)"
```